# How should I resolve this error? I have a problem with ruby variables

Tags: ruby

**Program**

The program is supposed to take input, convert it to a float and calculate that into a letter grade and a number. It should take it from all of the cases and when statements and print it.

**Code**

```
puts "Please enter your grade:"
grade = gets.chomp.to_f
puts "Please enter the amount the assignment is being graded on:"
outof = gets.chomp.to_f

finalresult = (grade / outof)*1000
puts "Your letter grade is #{$result} and your percentage is #{finalresult}."
$result = 0.00
case finalresult 
when finalresult == 0..399
  $result == "E"
when finalresult == 400..499
  $result == "D"
when finalresult == 500..549
  $result == "C-"
when finalresult == 550..599
  $result == "C"
when finalresult == 600..649
  $result == "C+"
when finalresult == 650..699
  $result == "B-"
when finalresult == 700..749
  $result == "B"
when finalresult == 750..799
  $result == "B+"
when finalresult == 800..849
  $result == "A-"
when finalresult == 850..899
  $result == "A"
when finalresult == 900..1000
  $result == "A+"
end
```

**Output/Error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/574pt.png)

Comment: BTW there are some semantic inconsistencies in your code: "grade" is a number when gathering input and becomes a letter (A–E) when printing the result. The variable names `result` and `finalresult` are somewhat ambiguous. And your "percentage" is actually [per mille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `finalresult ==` parts from `when` and use `=` instead of `==` to *assign* `$result`:

```
case finalresult 
when 0..399
  $result = "E"
when 400..499
  $result = "D"
when 500..549
  $result = "C-"
# ...
end
```

You might also want to replace `$result` with `result`, i.e. use a local variable instead of a global variable.

You might consider moving the `case` statement into a method:

```
def grade(value)
  case value
  when 0..399 then "E"
  when 400..499 then "D"
  when 500..549 then "C-"
  # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to simply use an array to associate the numeric grade with the letter grade:

```
NBR_GRADE_TO_LTR_GRADE = [
  [399, "E"], [499, "D"], [549, "C-"], [550, "C"], [649, "C+"], [699, "B-"],
  [749, "B"], [799, "B+"], [849, "A-"], [899, "A"], [1000, "A+"]
]
```

```
def ltr_grade(grade, outof)
  p_grade = (1000 * (grade.fdiv(outof))).round
  l_grade = NBR_GRADE_TO_LTR_GRADE.find { |nbr, _ltr| p_grade <= nbr }.last
  [l_grade, p_grade] 
end
```

---

```
grade = 80
outof = 100
puts "Your letter grade is %s and your numeric grade is %d." %
  ltr_grade(grade, outof)

Your letter grade is A- and your numeric grade is 800
```

```
grade = 10
outof = 100
puts "Your letter grade is %s and your numeric grade is %d." %
  ltr_grade(grade, outof)

Your letter grade is E and your numeric grade is 100.
```

---

The intermediate calculations for the first example are as follows.

```
grade = 80
outof = 100
p_grade = (1000 * (grade.fdiv(outof))).round
  #=> 800  
a = l_grade = NBR_GRADE_TO_LTR_GRADE.find { |nbr, _ltr| p_grade <= nbr }
  #=> [849, "A-"]
a.last
  #=> "A-"
```